# Macro shots using Nikon AF-S 55-300mm

Tags: lens, nikon, macro

I know, it's not a macro (or, in Nikon terms, Micro) lens. But, want to use it that way sometimes.

Though, for budget's sake, i was considering a Tamron AF 70-300mm(F/4-5.6 Di LD Macro), but, ended up buying Nikon 55-300mm for overall value. I tried to utilize a closeup filter, but it was a frustrating experience.

Is there any to utilize for macro shot by using any technique, or any close-up filter, or any other way ?

Do you have any experience to share?

p.s. My camera is a D5100

Comment: If you look at the [macro] tag, there are links to a number of questions that will help.  http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4741/how-can-i-take-a-macro-shot-without-a-macro-lens  and http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9341/what-macro-techniques-offer-an-alternative-to-expensive-optics  in particular

Comment: You can try extension tubes, but 55-300 mm zoom seems awkward for macro use no matter what method you use.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Bad news for me. Anyway, I also have a Nikon AF 50 1.8D. Is that good to go ?

Comment: This is not a duplicate, I wish stupid stack would not close these great questions redirect to a different barely related question. I wish someone would have answered this question.